# Time apart in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I run the following query in PostgreSQL (the following should work on MSSQL). The purpose is to see how much time apart to evens happened:

```
select ABS(CAST((a.timefield - b.timefield) as INT)) as 'Time Apart'
from a inner join b on (a.id = b.id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the type of "a.timefield" and "b.timefield" this should work:

```
SELECT ABS(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (a.timefield - b.timefield))) AS "Time Apart" FROM a INNER JOIN b ON (a.id = b.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.timefield - b.timefield
FROM a 
  INNER JOIN B on (a.id = b.id)
```

Will give you an interval data type